# Android MediaPlayer not playing sounds on button click

Tags: android, media-player

I'm new to android and I need it for a project I'm working on. I need it to play a sound by clicking a button. I followed online tutorials but my code does not play sounds at all and I'm getting an error on MediaPlayer Error(-19,0). I've tried a lot of the fixes I saw here and I can't seem to make it work. Any help? Here's the code

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)     getSystemService(MainActivity.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);

            Button buttonHello = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            buttonHello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MediaPlayer mp = Medi    aPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.button);
                    mp.start();
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletion    Listener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.release();

                        };
                    });
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: When is the error raised ? On `create()` or on `start` ? Is there any relevant message/trace in the exception ?

Comment: (Btw you should probably set the listener before starting the player)

Comment: Where you give the file to mediaplayer?

Answer (score 0):

This links http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/59.html has the great example to use MediaPlayer class to play song from raw folder.

To play song from **files** in the memory you can use the following code.

```
 MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
         mp.reset();
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();                       
         values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filename.getAbsolutePath());
          Uri selectedImage=RingtoneDownload.this.getContentResolver().insert(
                          MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                        try {
                            mp.setDataSource(RingtoneDownload.this,selectedImage);
                            mp.prepare();
                            mp.start();
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

This code is working for me while set the source from file.